# How do I write a function in python that takes as input 2 numbers, and 1 string

Tags: python

I tried to do it but my code doesn't work. When I call `operate(4,5,add)` I have a traceback that says `"name 'add' is not defined"`. Could you please help me ?

```
def operate(x,y,z):
    if (z == "add"):
        op = x+y
        print("%d + %d = %d" %(x, y, op))
    elif (z == "multiply"):
        op = x*y
        print("%d * %d = %d" %(x, y, op))
```

Comment: You missed quotation. `operate(4,5,"add") `

Answer (score 5):

`add` is not a string. `'add'` and `"add"` are strings. You need to call your function with `operate(4, 5, 'add')` or `operate(4, 5, "add")`.

Comment: Please mark this resolved since it answered your question.